# Debugging Kotlin in VSCode

Tags: kotlin, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm new to Kotlin. After downloading Kotlin and Java extensions on VSCode, I found myself struggling to debug (in Kotlin). I, therefore, started searching and found https://github.com/thunderz99/kt-sample-app, which works, but as I tried changing the code into mine, everything messed up and didn't work.

If it helps at all, the code I'm trying to debug is the next one:

```
class Solution {
    fun twoSum(nums: IntArray, target: Int): IntArray {
        for (i in 0..nums.size - 1)
            for (j in 0..nums.size - 1)
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                    return arrayOf(i, j).toIntArray()
        return intArrayOf()
    }
    fun main() {
        val nums = intArrayOf(2, 7, 11, 15)
        val target = 9
        println (twoSum(nums, target))
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I ended up debugging thanks to the [link before](https://github.com/thunderz99/kt-sample-app), however I don't know why it is working.

The configuration is the next:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "kotlin",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Kotlin Launch",
            "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "mainClass": "kt/sample/app/AppKt",
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

The class that I'm trying to debug is found in the "src/main/kotlin/kt/sample/app/App.kt" directory, and for it to work, it has to be something like this:

```
class App {
    val greeting: String = ""
}

// code here

fun main() {
    App.greeting
    // more code here
}
```

I would appreciate any help on letting me know how the configuration has to be, where to put the file I want to debug in a project and if I can debug a single file outside a full project

Comment: “everything messed up and didn't work.” — Can you expand on that, please? What did you see? Were there any error messages?

Comment: @gidds it simply didn't work, I mean, I debugged the one in the linking the configuration ruined smoothly, but when I changed it into my code, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing a number of curly braces. The keyword *for* requires the following code to be enclosed or nested in curly braces. The keyword *if* would also need curly braces if it were executing multiple lines of code afterwards. Your code would likely look something like this:

```
class Solution {
    fun twoSum(nums: IntArray, target: Int): IntArray {
        for (i in 0..nums.size - 1) {
            for (j in 0..nums.size - 1) {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                    return arrayOf(i, j).toIntArray()
            }
        }
        return intArrayOf()
    }
    fun main() {
        val nums = intArrayOf(2, 7, 11, 15)
        val target = 9
        println (twoSum(nums, target))
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you told me, and both codes end in the same output. Anyways, I'm not trying, in the long run, get the correct solution, I'm trying to get the correct configuration on vscode to be able to debug any time

Comment: Well, this answer does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information:

- What did you change?
- How does your pom.xml look like?
- What did you attempt to make it run?
- What is the command or terminal output?

I am not too experienced with Kotlin but I think, Kotlin requires you to define your `main()` as a global function, not as a method, otherwise it won't start.

To me, it seems the configuration is correct. In order to work, you need the appropriate `pom.xml`, the `tasks.json` and the `launch.json`. You only need to change the `mainClass` value in `launch.json` and the `sourceDirectory` Element in the `pom.xml` if you rename the folder structure.